# review my circle creating code( turtle, python)

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

im new to python and just started touching turtle. I made this code of circle drawing and i have a few questions:

```
import turtle
jo = turtle.Turtle()
def polygon(t, r, n, l):
    for i in range(30):
        jo.fd(n * l)
        jo.lt(r * 2 * 3.14)
print(polygon(jo, 2, 3, 4))
turtle.done()
```

1) i really dont understand how the code i wrote draw a circle.

2) are there any other ways to draw a circle in a similar sytax?

3) is this code is fine or I need to improve it?

Comment: You wrote this code but you don't understand it. Oookay. Anyhow, it is not a circle but a common approximation - [a regular polygon](https://www.voltage.com/math-2/approximating-a-circle-with-a-polygon/). Increase the diameter and you will see this. Also, if you let the turtle run several circles, you will notice that each round slightly differs for this reason. You also have rounding errors - e.g., you do not use pi but the approximation 3.14.

Comment: Yes I understand that it's not a perfect circle, the thing is I don't understand how this input create a look alike circle

Answer (score 0):

> i really dont understand how the code i wrote draw a circle.

By shear chance, perhaps.  You'll notice that the radius of the circle you draw (~27) has nothing to do with the radius you passed into your `polygon()` function (2).

You pass *radians* to the `left()` function:

```
jo.lt(r * 2 * 3.14)
```

although it takes *degrees* unless told otherwise.  You print the result of a function that doesn't return anything:

```
print(polygon(jo, 2, 3, 4))
```

Your turtle overshoots at the very end redrawing a small segment of the circle.  Finally, you pass a turtle *argument* to the `polygon()` function but ignore it and uses the *global* one instead.

> is this code is fine or I need to improve it?

I'd go with something more like:

```
from math import pi
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

TWO_PI = 2 * pi

def polygon(turtle, radius, sides):
    circumference = radius * TWO_PI

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.fd(circumference / sides)
        turtle.lt(TWO_PI / sides)

jo = Turtle()
jo.radians()

polygon(jo, 100, 30)

screen = Screen()

screen.mainloop()
```

> are there any other ways to draw a circle in a similar sytax?

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

jo = Turtle()

jo.circle(100, steps=30)

screen = Screen()

screen.mainloop()
```